# Regex to match pattern only if the line does not start with a character

Tags: python, regex

I have three perfectly working regexes:

```
(?<=drbd:(?!.*/dev/.*))[^,]+
/dev/drbd.+?(?=,)
(?<=phy:(?!.*drbd.*))[^,]+
```

I need all of them to only match if the line they're trying to match, does not start with a '#' symbol; that is, the line is not commented out.

All my attempts were matching the start of the line itself, but I want that to be just a condition to either match the pattern or not.

```
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vg0/xpto,xvda,rw']
#disk = [ 'drbd:resource23,xvda,rw']
disk = [ 'drbd:resource66,xvda,rw'
```

I need to match `/dev/vg0/xpto` and `resource66`. leaving `resource23` behind.

Also, I'm writing this for a python script, if anybody can give me a hint on how to make the regex or the script somehow match all the 'disks' in the file, I'd appreciate it! I tried adding some flags but no success.

Thank you!

Comment: I would just use `str.startswith` to filter the lines before applying your regexes.

Comment: Can you post the code you are wokring on?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this ?

```
import re

content = """disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vg0/xpto,xvda,rw']
#disk = [ 'drbd:resource23,xvda,rw']
disk = [ 'drbd:resource66,xvda,rw'"""


get_paths = re.compile(r'(?mi)^(?!#).+(?:phy:|drbd:)(.+?),').findall
paths = get_paths(content)
print(paths)

# ['/dev/vg0/xpto', 'resource66']
```

Answer (score 0):

File 'testfile.txt' data:

```
disk = ['phy:/dev/vg0/xpto,xvda,rw']

disk = ['drbd:resource66,xvda,rw']

with open('testfile.txt') as f_Obj:
    lines = f_Obj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            do_something...
```

Comment: The caveat with this answer is that it must strictly start with a '#' character. If the line has whitespace preceding the '#' the `line.startswith('#')` will return False. Something like `re.search(r'\S*#', line) is None` would cover that.

Comment: well if the line has whitespace preceding the '#' we can use line.lstrip().startswith('#') method and it will return True